# Inserting text into the string in iOS

Tags: objective-c, ios

I need my user to enter numbers to type his telephone number.The user can only enter 8 numbers(for eg. XXXXXXXX). I need to change the phone number to be in the format XX-XX-XXXX.

This is what I have tried:

```
[tfDID.text insertString:@"-" atIndex:2];
[tfDID.text insertString:@"-" atIndex:5];
```

But it is returning me an error saying:

```
No Visible @interface for 'NSString' declares the selector 'insertString:atIndex:'
```

Need some guidance on this. Sorry if this is a stupid question.

Comment: Can you add your declaration of tfDID in .h file here ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`No Visible @interface for 'NSString' declares the selector 'insertString:atIndex:'`

As you are trying to mutate the textbox's value, which returns you NSString.

NSString object can not be mutated, so convert it into a mutable string then manupulate it.

Make your string `NSMutableString`.

As,

```
NSMutableString *tfDIDString=[NSMutableString stringWithString:tfDID.text];
[tfDIDString insertString:@"-" atIndex:2];
[tfDIDString insertString:@"-" atIndex:5];
```

Answer (score 4):

`[UITextField text]` is `NSString`, you need to declare local variable of `NSMutableString` and perform `insertString` operations on it

Hope it helps you

Answer (score 1):

Implement `<UITextFieldDelegate>` and then do:

```
-(void)textFieldDidChange:(UITextField*)textField
{
    if( textField.text.length == 2 || textField.text.length == 5 ){
        textField.text = [textField.text stringByAppendingString:@"-"];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Completely agree with the answer suggesting making it a mutable string.
Just to play devils advocate you could do:

```
NSString *partOne = [NSString stringWithRange:NSMakeRange(0,2)];
NSString *partTwo = [NSString stringWithRange:NSMakeRange(2,2)];
NSString *partThree = [NSString stringWithRange:NSMakeRange(4,4)];

NSString *formattedNumber = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@-%@-%@",partOne,partTwo,partThree];
```

I've written it out longhand but you could compress the string declarations for the parts in to the stringWithFormat call if you don't mind nesting and sacrifcing a bit of readability.